# If $x+y+z=1$, prove that $9xyz+1\ge 4(xy+yz+zx)$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> If $x+y+z=1$, prove that $9xyz+1\ge 4(xy+yz+zx)$ for $x,y,z\in \Bbb R^+$

I tried to solve this by splitting  $9xyz$  as $3xyz+3xyz+3xyz$ and taking all the terms to the LHS before factoring, but I was unable to.

Also tried using Schur's inequality, but that didn't work either.

Comment: What about Newton inequalities?

Comment: Does it help that $(xy+yz+zx)=\frac{xyz}{x}+\frac{xyz}{y}+\frac{xyz}{z}$?

Comment: I assume you meant $x,y,z\geq0$, as otherwise $x=y=1,z=-1$ is a counterexample.  Note the condition is required for Schur's inequality, as used in the accepted answer.  One can solve the problem by showing that if the cubic $t^3-t^2+at-b$ has 3 non-negative real roots (counted with multiplicity), then  $9b+1\geq4a$.  However this is longwinded compared to the accepted answer.  One thing that drops out from it is that equality holds at the center of the triangle and at the 3 midpoints of the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearranging $$9xyz+(x+y+z)^3-4(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)$$ gives us

$$\sum_{cyc} (x^3+xyz-x^2y-x^2z) $$

which is $\ge 0$ because it is Schur's inequality

Comment: Cool, but it seems like magic. How did you come up with it? Anything in particular which motivated this approach?

Comment: @aman I just homogenized it, remained part came easily